# The type cannot be used as type parameter 'TTo' in the generic type or method. There is no implicit reference conversion

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container

I'm currently trying to use Unity to inject ViewModels into my WPF Application.

I tend to use a `ViewModelLocator` class to store all of my ViewModels in one area, for quick navigation between them

I've split up my app into four projects:

`KeystonePP.Models` - Holds my EF Model

`KeystonePP.Startup` - Main startup logic

`KeystonePP.ViewModels`- ViewModels and their interfaces

`KeystonePP.Views` - Views

I have an `IViewModelLocator` interface in a separate project: `KeystonePP.ViewModels`

```
public interface IViewModelLocator
{
    // No code here. Just a contract
}
```

This is implemented by my `ViewModelLocator` class

```
public class ViewModelLocator : ObservableObject, IViewModelLocator
{
    // Lots of code here
}
```

In my `KeystonePP.Startup` project, I have adjusted my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` constructor as such:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow (IViewModelLocator viewModelLocator)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModelLocator;
    }
}
```

However, when I attempt the following code in `App.xaml.cs`, I'm getting an error warning:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Startup Logic for App
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnStartup (StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IViewModelLocator, MainWindow>();
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> The type 'KeystonePP.Startup.MainWindow' cannot be used as type parameter 'TTo' in the generic type or method 'UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType(IUnityContainer, params InjectionMember[])'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'KeystonePP.Startup.MainWindow' to 'KeystonePP.ViewModels.Utility.Interfaces.IViewModelLocator'.

Have I gone too complicated, or am I missing something simple setting up Unity?

Comment: You are mapping the wrong types when trying to register them

Comment: @jDave1984 `MainWindow` class does not implement `IViewModelLocator`

Comment: The error is saying that `MainWindow` _itself_ must implement `IViewModelLocator`, which it doesn't right now (asking for it in the constructor doesn't cut it). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm confused, don't I want to inject `MainWindow` with an `IViewModelLocator`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to register abstractions with their implementations.

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IViewModelLocator, ViewModelLocator>();
container.RegisterType<MainWindow>();
```

that way when you call to resolve `MainWindow`

```
var mainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
mainWindow.Show();
```

the container will know how to inject the implementation based on the abstraction when resolving.

Comment: So do I want both `MainWindow` and `ViewModelLocator` to implement `IViewModelLocator`?

Comment: @jDave1984 there is no need to do that. `MainWindow` **depends** on `IViewModelLocator` and does not need to be derived from the dependency

Comment: AH! That makes a ton of sense now! Thanks